# Is there a difference between the PC and Console versions of Assassin's Creed?

Tags: version-differences, assassins-creed

While playing the PC Version of *Assassin's Creed* (which on steam is called the Director's Cut Edition) I've started noticing some things about it which I don't recall from the Console version, some of which I asked my dad if he remembered them from the consoles and he didn't remember either.

- PC: When leaving the fortress in Masyaf from Memory 4 you can fast travel to the other's cities to either their outskirts or the Assassin's Bureau

  - Console: you had to leave Masyaf (all the way out of the village) and you'd only travel to the outskirts of other cities
- PC: there are informant missions to destroy shop stands by throwing people into them

  - Console: neither me or my dad recall ever having these
- PC: there are Informant Archer Assassination Missions

  - Console: I don't recall these and the one in Jerusalem in Memory 4 (Majd Addin) I seem to recall was a timed assassination challenge where the targets were guards on the street

I am wondering if there really is a difference between the PC and Console versions of *Assassin's Creed*, of if the instances above is just that I had forgotten a lot more than I had previously thought.